# ERROR: No such service: nginx when building wordpress with docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am having an issue in which after the installation of wordpress and the creation of the user with login I am getting a wp error: `One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.` and is asking to add the following code to the `wp-config.php`.

`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`

I have added this code as asked but is not working.

In addition, I am also adding the error:

```
ERROR: No such service: nginx
DUMP FILE BEFORE:  -rw-r--r-- 1 macbook staff 30M 1 Mar 17:41 ./db/dmp/bootstrap.sql
```

I am using macos and I have also trying to rebuild but with no success.

Comment: You said you're adding the code to the `wp-config.php`, but what code?  This sounds, on the surface, as if your DB credentials are incorrect.  WP either can't access or can't find the DB specified or the DB is incomplete.

Comment: Sure, I dont know why but I am having issue with nginx of docker. Tried even in windows but with no success. I am thinking the issue is with `nginx`.

Comment: WordPress doesn't provide a docker container for production use, the official docker image for WordPress is made by Docker, not WordPress. Currently it isn't possible to answer this question or reproduce the problem with the information available

Comment: @TonyDjukic sorry I have added the code that was missing.